# Prove that the shift operator $(Ax)(t)=x(t−a)$ not compact.

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

Prove that the shift operator $(Ax)(t)=x(t−a)$ not compact in the space of bounded continuous functions on R.

Comment: There is at least 1 word missing in this problem.

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: Use the fact that if the image of the unit ball is compact under A then any sequence in it must have a convergent subsequence

Comment: I do not know where to start.

Comment: @user152384, that's a poor excuse. You start with the definition of what it means for an operator to be compact. So after doing that, what's your problem?

Comment: The fact that I do not understand functional analysis, no matter how tried. And if nesmog decide then I dropped out, so please help.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $A$ has a continuous inverse (namely $(A^{-1}x)(t)=x(t+a)$ and if $S$ and $T$ are two bounded operators with $T$ compact then $ST$ is compact.

Comment: What is S and T?

Comment: Two general operators. Use this with $T:=A$ and $S:=A^{-1}$.

Comment: Why not ST compact?

Comment: In this case, $ST$ is the identity, which cannot be compact on an _infinite dimensional_ normed space.

Comment: Why S is bounded?

Comment: You can show that $\lVert Sx\rVert=\lVert x\rVert$.